# When should I send the so-called “inquiry email”?

Tags: graduate-school, research-undergraduate

I’ve heard that, prior to applying, undergraduates sometimes express interest to faculty members of graduate schools via email. I know that this is most often done (fairly?) close to the time of application, however, I still have a year before applying (graduating June 2021).

Is it unheard of for students to contact faculty a year before applying so they can establish some sort of research relationship? By “research relationship”, I mean something akin to typical undergraduate mathematics research (though with a professor at another institution), however diluted it may become due to distance. I’m interested in hearing how feasible this is!

Comment: Preferably away from final exam weeks (May and December). This kind of contact only works well if it is organic and stems from genuine interest; doing it too close to application season is only counterproductive.

Comment: Which country? The answer might depend on this.

Comment: Ah -- good point. The university I am attending as an undergraduate is in the US, but I'm not ruling out the possibility of applying somewhere foreign.